# Play video and stick to the mouse - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a video to be played and stick to the mouse pointer when the visitor hovers the red box. When he leaves the red box with the mouse the video stops and disappears.

This is what I got so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3599/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#tail').css({
       left:  e.pageX + 20,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});

var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}

$( "#red" ).mouseover(function() {

   $("#videosList").css("display","block");

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tail">
                  <div id="videosList">  



<div class="video">
    <video class="thevideo" loop preload="none">
      <source src="http://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
  Hover mouse over video. Desktop only [ Obviously! ;) ]
</div> 
</div>

<div id="red" style="height:200px;width:200px;background:red;">

</div>
```

Comment: And what is not working?  Can you place a jsfiddle?

Comment: I already did so, http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3599/ I am not sure whats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes, it's working now [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lexicalnoscope/hj57k/3606/)

There were a few syntax things that were a little off, and the hover event needed to be bound to `#red` rather than to `.video`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close to being right. You can use jQuery's mouseleave() function to hide your video when your mouse leaves the red box. I also used jQuery's hide() and show() methods instead of modifying the css of the videosList.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
      $('#tail').css({
         left:  e.pageX + 20,
         top:   e.pageY
      });
  });

  var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

  function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
  }

  function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
  }

  $( "#red" ).mouseover(function() {
    $("#videosList").show();
  });

  $('#red').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#videosList').hide();
  });
});
```